# how to approximate a latitude/longitude to show an approximate location on the map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, geospatial, geocoding

I have an exact longitude/latitude coordinates of an user (retrieving by GPS). But to keep privacy I don't want to show a precise coordinates in the website. I would like to return the longitude/latitude that are randomly moved between 250m to 500m. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2):

This should do.

```
var latitude = longitude = 24;

// Add offset to the coordinates
latitude += getRandomLongitudeOffset(250, 500);
longitude += getRandomLongitudeOffset(250, 500, latitude);


/* 
    Calculate one meter in degrees
    1 degree = ~111km
    1km in degree = ~0.0089
    1m in degree = ~0.0000089
*/
const COEF = 0.0000089;

/**
 * Returns an offset for coordinates in range [min, max]
*/
function getRandomLatitudeOffset(min, max){
    return getRandomInt(min, max) * COEF;
}


function getRandomLongitudeOffset(min, max, latitude){
    return (getRandomInt(min, max) * COEF) / Math.cos(latitude * 0.018);
}


/**
 * Returns a random integer between min (inclusive) and max (inclusive)
 * Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
 */
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```